# Does a precise/accurate timing method exist?

Tags: php, linux, optimization, time

I've seen many ways to time a script - from getrusage(), microtime(), and others.  Ideally there would be a way that gives the true run time, factors out "noise", for example the scheduler, so that every time I run a self contained script I get the exact same answer as it is a deterministic process.  Is the ideal not possible and if so what is the next best solution?  Thanks in advance.

Comment: 6 questions, and 0 accepted answers.. you should fix that.

Comment: I don't know of any situation where precision of software timing is of any value. Are you building a clock based on running this in the inner loop? You can expect noise in time measurements, due to any number of factors. Two, maybe three, decimal places of accuracy are about all you can expect, or that mean anything.

Comment: "Independent of other variabels" (sic) is a meaningless statement.  You *aren't* independent of other variables because that's how it works.  You can work to mitigate these variables but short of coding on bare metal you're going to be contending with the whole OS.  And even if you did, there are timing irregularities in the clock chips, in the frequencies modulated by the power supply, etc etc.

Comment: A script/program takes a defined amount of time to run. Independent of other variabels it take the same time every time. Because a computer is a detrministic system, it is possible to get a repeatable run time for each script with perfect precision and accuracy. Wether or not this tool exists I do not know and that was the question. Currently using microtime I have not got any thing I can use regarding both the accuracy and the precision as far as raw performance goes...but for comparison to larger values it works fine.

Comment: For example - when comparing client processing time, server side processing time, and network transit time, simply using time() works fine.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should look into [Xdebug](http://www.xdebug.org/). Runtime profiling will give you a good idea of execution time as well as things like callstack graphs and memory usage.

Comment: In specific, you want to use [the profiling features](http://www.xdebug.org/docs/profiler) xdebug offers.

Comment: PDT (PHP Development Tool), an Eclipse plug-in contains Xdebug. Xdebug should output data that I can visualize with kcachegrind. Seems the current effort is figuring out what all the pieces and getting them installed correctly.